# Laravel Eloquent query - Could not convert to int

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make build a query on Eloquent using pluck, but for some reason, the return message given to me is:

```
Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Housing_around/resources/views/admin/tasks/create.blade.php)
```

Can someone give me a clue on what is happening?

controller method:

```
$house = House::findOrFail(Auth::user()->house->id);

            $jobs = Job::pluck('name', 'id')->all();
            $categories = Category::pluck('name', 'id')->all();
            $users = User::where('house_id', $house)->pluck('name', 'id');
```

My view seems to be normal:

```
<div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        {!! Form::select('user_id',[''=>'Chose user'] + $users,null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to concatinate a collection and an array. So, change this:

```
[''=>'Chose user'] + $users
```

To:

```
[''=>'Chose user'] + $users->toArray()
```